# index value cannot updated

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Here I am using array to store date in local-storage. first add data that is stored after add another one the index value not increased. The newly add data only shows.

```
function save() {
            var task = [];
            localStorage.getItem('task');
            task.push(document.getElementById("txt1").value);
            console.log(task);
            localStorage.setItem('array', task);
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you do this due `localStorage` can store strings, not objects (or arrays)..

Comment: Everytime, you are initialising a new array inside which you are pushing one value.What do you expect to get increased?

Comment: You probably meant to something like: `var task = localStorage.getItem('task');`

Comment: You need `var task = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('task'));` and `localStorage.setItem('task', JSON.stringify(task));`

Comment: You should store your "task" array as a json text value (stringify). Then when "save()", get localstorage item, dump the json, add item, and re-save (=re-stringify). You can only store string values in localStorage.

Comment: `localStorage.getItem('task');` ... gets the value, and throws it away, doing nothing